# problems running xamp

Tags: mysql, xampp, port

I am using a open source document repositary kordil edbms which works fine in my windows 7 machine .
But when i installed it in windows small business server, xamp is not running. when i start task manager httpd itself is not getting shown. I went to xamp control panel and it says error running mysql busy.I have share point in that machine which also has localhost 80.
So I changed the apache port.
I changed the apache port in httpd.conf file in 2  places

1. listen
2. server name

It seems i need to change the port for mysql also. Now what is the option to change the port for xamp mysql or am i going wrong some where else. Please also look at the screenshot of xamp control panel.

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quit `Skype` and then restart all services from your `XAMPP` and let me know if its work or not.

Port conflict as Skype also consumes 80 by default

Click on SCM and manage services by starting and stopping.

[image]

**EDIT**

check this link for both to work with - http://www.binodranabhat.com.np/blog/using-xampp-and-iis-together/

Comment: hey thanx for the quick reply.. i found the problem already, i quit skype b4 i start xamp still it dont work...

Comment: @user2038655 ok..let me chk the screenshot once more then

Comment: @raghavbhat chk my screenshot, chk for the IIS..may be a server war/conflict

Comment: i did what ever u told me.. now in my xamp control panel it says mysql is running. but the screen is not coming..' may be a server war/conflict' i didnot do anything for this.. please tell me what should i do for this conflict.to make both work

Comment: @raghavbhat please add @ before my name while commenting so that i can get a response from the system that u made any comment..i havent tried this but i will surely let u know

Comment: @raghavbhat Please check this and let me know if it helps you or not http://www.binodranabhat.com.np/blog/using-xampp-and-iis-together/

Comment: @swapnesh , progress now i can see httpd in task manager and mysql and apache both seems to be running when i look at the xamp control panel. but still i cant see the screen

Comment: .one thing more...sometimes error_logs prove to be your good frnds too..check those as well

Comment: @swapnesh in my case its not actually blank screen.. i want to run a doc rep.. so the screen needs to come when i give the proper url.. now i am getting the error.. usual error like if url is typed wrongly.. 80 changed to 85

Comment: @raghavbhat what about server log? what error they are showing?

Comment: [Wed Jul 01 11:32:13 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/xampp/htdocs/kordil_edms/css, referer: http://localhost/kordil_edms/main_category_login.php
[Wed Jul 01 11:32:15 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not exist: C:/xampp/htdocs/kordil_edms/css, referer: http://localhost/kordil_edms/global_group_login.php
[Wed Jul 01 11:32:19 2009] [error] [client 127.0.0.1] File does not

Comment: @swapnesh actually all files are there in proper place

Comment: @swapnesh hey thnx man,now it works. actually the answer which sent by u and the link sent by u is correct. while doing changes i forgot to change the apache port properly. i accept the answer. thnx

Answer (score 0):

MYSQL not working because xampp which path excepting that path not  getting automatically .
that is reason behind xampp mysql not start

go to window +R press then open cmd with run as administration  then type this command

```
 sc delete mysql
```

then after start mysql problem resolved.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

**Fixing Apache Port Conflicts**

Another error message that is pretty common to see when working with XAMPP is a notification in the XAMPP control panel that the ports Apache needs to use, ports 443 and 80, are already being used by another application.

A message from the XAMPP control panel letting us know Skype is using ports 443 and 80
In the case of the error message in the image above, this is a pretty easy fix. The offending application is Skype. If you see the same message, close Skype completely and restart XAMPP to solve the problem. Skype is a frequent-flier on the port-blocking scene and pretty easy to identify and remediate. Unfortunately, things aren’t always so simple.